# Can anyone fix this code

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I'm trying to follow a tutorial to customize the appearance of the announcements list, however, they don't provide downloadable files and the code they provide on the web page is messed up somehow and I don;t know enough about JavaScript or SharePoint to fix it.

https://www.c5insight.com/Resources/Blog/tabid/88/entryid/653/how-you-make-sharepoint-announcements-grab-attention-easily-using-csr.aspx

Copy of Code:

```
[sourcecode language='javascript' padlinenumbers='true' htmlscript='false' gutter='true'] (function () { document.write('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>'); document.write('<script src="/Style%20Library/CriticalNews/js/homepage_message.js"><\/script>'); document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/CriticalNews/css/homepage_message.css" />'); // Load our custom CSS /*var cssId = 'myCss'; // you could encode the css path itself to generate id.. if (!document.getElementById(cssId)) { var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; var link = document.createElement('link'); link.id = cssId; link.rel = 'stylesheet'; link.type = 'text/css'; link.href = '/Style Library/CriticalNews/css/homepage_message.css'; link.media = 'all'; head.appendChild(link); }*/ /* * Initialize the variable that store the overrides objects. */ var overrideCtx = {}; overrideCtx.Templates = {}; //   Assign functions or plain html strings to the templateset objects: //   header, footer and item. overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<div class='center'>"; overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = "</div>"; // This template is assigned to the CustomItem function. overrideCtx.Templates.Item = CustomItem; //overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1; overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 104; // Register the template overrides. SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx); })(); /* * This function builds the output for the item template. * Uses the Context object to access announcement data. */ function CustomItem(ctx) { // Build a listitem entry for every announcement in the list. /* <div class="notification fail canhide"><span>ERROR!</span> This is an error message.</div> <div class="notification info canhide"><span>INFORMATION:</span> This is an information.</div> <div class="notification warning canhide"><span>WARNING!</span> This is a warning message.</div> */ //var ret = "<li>This is a " + ctx.CurrentItem.MoreText + "</li>"; if (ctx.CurrentItem["MessageType"] == "Informational (blue)") { var ret = "<div class='notification info'>" + ctx.CurrentItem["Body"].replace("<p>","").replace("</p>","") + "</div>"; } else if (ctx.CurrentItem["MessageType"] == "Warning (yellow)") { var ret = "<div class='notification warning'>" + ctx.CurrentItem["Body"].replace("<p>","").replace("</p>","") + "</div>"; } else if (ctx.CurrentItem["MessageType"] == "Critical (red)") { var ret = "<div class='notification fail'>" + ctx.CurrentItem["Body"].replace("<p>","").replace("</p>","") + "</div>"; } return ret; } [/sourcecode]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Posting someone else's 'broken' code on here and hoping the community will fix it for you without any effort of your own is really poor behavior and not befitting of this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this site is specifically for asking SharePoint and SharePoint related questions more than fixing broken code, i'l add that the the plugin that were supposed to render the code are broken.

If you ever happen to cross the same thing again, you can always right click on the page, using any browser and choose "View Source". That way, you can find the code with somewhat correct formatting. (As in this case, it was correct).

Here you go.

```
(function () {

    document.write('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">;<\/script>;');
    document.write('<script src="/Style%20Library/CriticalNews/js/homepage_message.js">;<\/script>;');
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/CriticalNews/css/homepage_message.css" />;');

    // Load our custom CSS
    /*var cssId = 'myCss';   // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
    if (!document.getElementById(cssId))
    {
        var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var link  = document.createElement('link');
        link.id   = cssId;
        link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.href = '/Style Library/CriticalNews/css/homepage_message.css';
        link.media = 'all';
        head.appendChild(link);
    }*/

    /*
     * Initialize the variable that store the overrides objects. 
     */
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

//  Assign functions or plain html strings to the templateset objects:
//  header, footer and item.
    overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<div class='center'>;";
    overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = "</div>;";

//  This template is assigned to the CustomItem function.
    overrideCtx.Templates.Item = CustomItem;
    //overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
    overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 104;

//       Register the template overrides.
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();

/*
 * This function builds the output for the item template.
 * Uses the Context object to access announcement data.
 */
function CustomItem(ctx) {
    // Build a listitem entry for every announcement in the list.
    /*
    <div class="notification fail canhide">;<span>;ERROR!</span>; This is an error message.</div>;
    <div class="notification info canhide">;<span>;INFORMATION:</span>; This is an information.</div>;
    <div class="notification warning canhide">;<span>;WARNING!</span>; This is a warning message.</div>;
    */
    //var ret = "<li>;This is a " + ctx.CurrentItem.MoreText + "</li>;";
    if (ctx.CurrentItem["MessageType"] == "Informational (blue)")
    {
        var ret = "<div class='notification info'>;" + ctx.CurrentItem["Body"].replace("<p>;","").replace("</p>;","") + "</div>;";
    }
    else  if (ctx.CurrentItem["MessageType"] == "Warning (yellow)")
    {
        var ret = "<div class='notification warning'>;" + ctx.CurrentItem["Body"].replace("<p>;","").replace("</p>;","") + "</div>;";
    }
    else  if (ctx.CurrentItem["MessageType"] == "Critical (red)")
    {
        var ret = "<div class='notification fail'>;" + ctx.CurrentItem["Body"].replace("<p>;","").replace("</p>;","") + "</div>;";
    }
    return ret;
}
```